# Is there a way for Eloquent whereHas to only get() the matching results?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following function

```
public function index(Request $request)
  {
    $results = Service::whereHas('conditions', function ($query) use ($request){
      $query->whereIn('id', $request->conditions);
    })
    ->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($request){

      $ran = false;
      foreach($request->locations as $location)
      {
        if(!$ran)
        {
          $query->Where('town', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')
          ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$location.'%');
        }
        else
        {
          $query->orWhere('town', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')
          ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$location.'%');
        }
        $ran = true;
      }
    })
    ->with('types', 'contacts', 'locations.datetimes')->toSql();

    dd($results);
  }
```

which produces

```
select * from `services` where exists 
  (select * from `conditions` inner join `condition_service` on `conditions`.`id` = `condition_service`.`condition_id` where `services`.`id` = `condition_service`.`service_id` and `id` in (13, 14) and `conditions`.`deleted_at` is null) 
and exists 
  (select * from `service_locations` inner join `service_location_service` on `service_locations`.`id` = `service_location_service`.`service_location_id` where `services`.`id` = `service_location_service`.`service_id` and 
    (`town` like 'manchester' or `city` like 'manchester' or `town` like 'crewe' or `city` like 'crewe') 
  and `service_locations`.`deleted_at` is null) and `services`.`deleted_at` is null
```

The problem is the `whereHas` on locations brings back all results, whereas I only want the result where the town/city is a match. Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to group your location query using the callback which wraps the query in `()` and just process the first location directly remove it from array and iterate over loop. so below code should work in your case.

```
    $results = Service::whereHas('conditions', function ($query) use ($request){
      $query->whereIn('id', $request->conditions);
    })
    ->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($request){
        $locations = $request->locations;
        $query->where(function($builder) use($locations){
          $builder->where('town', 'like', '%' . $locations[0] . '%')
            ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$locations[0].'%');
          unset($locations[0]); //remove first item as it is processed
          foreach($locations as $location) {
            $builder->orWhere('town', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')
              ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$location.'%');
          }
        });
    });
```

let me know if you find any problem with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out late last night.

I moved the with() to the top of the query and made a callback on locations.

```
public static function newGetSearchResults($request)
    {
      return Service::with(['types', 'contacts', 'locations.datetimes', 'locations' => function($query) use($request) {

        $ran = false;
        foreach($request->locations as $location)
        {
          if(!$ran)
          {
            $query->Where('town', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')
            ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$location.'%');
          }
          else
          {
            $query->orWhere('town', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')
            ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$location.'%');
          }
          $ran = true;
        }
      }])
      ->whereHas('conditions', function ($query) use ($request){
        $query->whereIn('id', $request->conditions);
      })->get();
    }
```

Comment: I also think I can sort out that horrid `$ran` flag using Parameter Grouping https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping